# what is the proper json download policy for bucket in localhost minio?

Tags: asp.net-core, minio

i want to set download policy for minio bucket on localhost in asp.net core.
i wrote below code.but it dont work. can anyone help me? thanks.

```
string policy = @"{{""Version"":""2012-10-17"",""Statement"":[{{""Action"":[""s3:GetObject"", ""s3:ListBucket""],""Effect"":""Allow"",""Principal"":{{""AWS"":[""*""]}},""Resource"":[""arn:aws:s3:::bucket2/*""],""Sid"":""AddPerm""}}";

await minioClient.SetPolicyAsync("bucket2", policy);
```

Comment: Hi. MEeting the same problem herer. Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with it a moment, I founded out a workaround to find out:

1. First I opened my [minio web client](http://localhost:9000) and checked my bucket's policy. I found out that it's *the same as an S3 one*.
2. Now you could [generate your own policy](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-client-complete-guide) and use them. You can also use the [AWS Policy generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) to have an idea of the JSON format. Make sure to provide accurate information.

When you give your `endpoint`, your `secretKey` and your `accessKey`, it will find out in your minio, which bucket/resource you are talking about.

This example worked with me.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```